# Why does an awaited Redux action creator not await properly? (React Native)

Tags: javascript, react-native, asynchronous, redux, react-redux

In my React Native app, I have an action creator that dispatches an action to update the state in the Redux store. I call this action creator with 'await' and then do a setState(), but I noticed the Redux store is getting updated AFTER the setState is completed. My code looks like this:

```
updateFunction = async () => {
  await this.props.actionCreator1();
  this.setState({property1: this.props.property1});
}
```

I 'await'ed the action dispatch because I need the store to be updated before I setState(). I must be misunderstanding what gets returned etc when you dispatch an action, because the store does not get updated until after setState() runs. Can anyone explain why this could occur?

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

This is how I bind my Redux store to my component

```
const Component1 = connect(
  state => ({
    property1: state.Reducer1.property1
  }),
  dispatch => bindActionCreators({
    actionCreator1: ActionCreators.actionCreator1
  }, dispatch)
)(Component1)
```

This is where I create the action creator in actions.js

```
export const ActionCreators = {
  actionCreator1: () => ({type: 'actionCreator1', property1: 'value'})
}
```

This is where I reduce the actions in reducer.js

```
const initialState = {
  property1: undefined
}

export default (state = initialState, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case('actionCreator1'): {
      return {
        ...state,
        property1: action.property1
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You should not rely on waiting for your actionCreator (Setting state afterwards/etc). The action should fire, and as a result your redux stores should change, which should trigger a rerender of the component. That's where your state change should be.

Comment: @FrankerZ I agree, and that's how I'd normally do it and how I'm doing it now. I'm more just curious to understand where the asynchronicity occurs in the sub-optimal way I was experimenting with here, just in order to understand the details of how Redux works.

Comment: There is nothing asynchronous about redux. Anything asynchronous is called side effects, and you're expected to use something like redux-thunk, redux-saga, or redux-observable

Comment: @FrankerZ You're right, I'm using redux-saga and when I console.logged at different points in the code it's the side effect (made a call to an API in my saga) that causes the asynchronicity. If you want to post an answer to this post I can update/accept it. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @gkeenley You are not supposed to use await on a function that doesn't return a Promise, to make it work either you can wrap your action creator so that it returns a promise then resolves to the value you want, or do a different approach not relying on async-await.

Answer (score 0):

You are not supposed to use await on a function that doesn't return a Promise, to make it work either you can wrap your action creator so that it returns a promise then resolves to the value you want, or do a different approach not relying on async-await.

You can define your action creator like below:

```
export const ActionCreators = {
  actionCreator1: () => new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      return resolve({type: 'actionCreator1', property1: 'value'})
  });
}
```

It will work if you added `redux-thunk` middle ware.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure you are using React/Redux best practices. You are using action which changes the redux state but at the same time you are trying to use setState which updates the state of React. Moreover, your code does not execute how you expect it because your `await` function is not `promise` based.

---

This does implicitly responds to your question. Take the functions below as an example:

```
function something1(){
  setTimeout(() => console.log('before'), 2000);
}

function something2(){
  var result = new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(console.log('before')) ,2000));
  return result;
}

function el(){
  console.log('after')
}

updateFunction = async () => {
  await something1(); // await something2();
  el();
  return 'done';
};
```

and try first to run `updateFunction()` in your console. Because function `something1()` is not `promise` based you will see that it will not `await` and the string `'after'` will be printed first. Now inside your `updateFunction()` try to change `await something1()` with `something2()` in your console again. You will see that the rest of the `el()` function will `await` for function `something2()` to finish first and your console will print out the strings `'before'` and then `'after'`. Hope this clarifies things a bit.

Comment: thanks for your reply.
Re "You are using ... state of React": this is intentional. In this particular app the state of the component (this.state.property) is not always supposed to match the Redux state (this.props.property).
Re "your await function is not promise based": Do you mean that dispatching an action creator does not return a promise? I've always understood it to be the case that if the awaited expression returns a value instead of a promise, the expression will return a promise resolved with the returned value. Could you elaborate more on what you mean here?

Comment: "You are using action which changes the redux state but at the same time you are trying to use setState which updates the state of React"

This is just plain incorrect. Local (ephemeral) state does not belong in Redux. setState is for local state and it is fully intended to be mixed with Redux.